# Getting JSON data stored in local machine and print over JSP using JS

Tags: javascript, json

Can anyone tell me how to access JSON file to java script without using the JQUERY ,AJAX.
I tried with JQUERY and AJAX its working but not able to do with JS alone.I have searched every where but i dint get any solution.whether it need any external JS file to use??

Comment: Do you get an error with jQuery?  Can you be more specific about your problem and show us your code?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library so by definition if it's possible in jQuery it's also possible without it. You need to show your code for anyone to be able to tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: its working with jquery and ajax.i want it make work only with js.I have a json file in my d drive.want to access the value to web page using js alone..is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular AJAX.

```
var text; //Declare text as a global variable for debugging purposes (my personal preference)
var getInfo = new XMLHttpRequest();
getInfo.open("GET", "smile.json", true /*MUST make this true for AJAX*/);
getInfo.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //this = getInfo
    if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) { //When it has gotten a 200 OK response back and it's ready...
        text = this.response;
        [do stuff]
    }
});
getInfo.send();
```

I suggest the [AJAX tutorial from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP) if you don't know how to use AJAX with vanilla JavaScript (no libraries).

Comment: Hi,I have already done using jquery and ajax,my doubt is its possible only with java script.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with JavaScript. You can learn about it at [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP).